# How to catch [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]

Tags: php, symfony, exception, ssh

I'm trying to make a php command using symfony to connect through ssh to a server.
It's all okay, but if i can't connect to server (server unreachable) i take this error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]             
Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to skin-master on port 22
```

This is okay but if i try to catch the error doing something like this:

```
try{
                $exec=$this->ssh_connect($cinema);
            }
            catch(\Exception $e){
                echo $e;
                $this->no_connection($em,$cinema);
                continue;
```

I continue to have the error so i can't control this exception.
How can I do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Why is there a `continue` in the `catch` section?

Comment: Because is in a for statemant.

Answer (score 0):

simply catch the exception explicitly

```
try {

} catch (\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException $e) {

}
```

if you need to catch other exceptions as well you can do it like this

```
try {

} catch (\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException $e) {

} catch (\Some\Other\Exception $e) {

} catch (\Exception $e) {

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe because is a warning that symfony catch. Is possible control this warning?

Comment: how does it not work? what hapens when using this code?

Comment: The same thing that happen if i use try{} catch(\Exception $e){}

Comment: Symfony is in the root namespace?

Comment: In the root namespace? What?

Comment: can you do `new \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException;`? if not you need to find out the proper namespace...

Comment: then you can also catch the exception as i wrote above. what exactly is happening which you don't want to?

Comment: I don't want that the program stop with this warning i just want call another function and continue but i take : [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]             
  Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to skin-master on port 22

Comment: your problem must be somewhere else. in the `catch` block remove all code and add `echo 'catched '. get_class($e);` what does it say then?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, this warnign was not throw up by the connection. Thank you. With \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException $e I cant catch this.

Comment: np, because you are a new user to stackoverflow: you may accept and upvote my answer if it really helped ;)

Comment: Just do it :) Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To check a connection. You can use:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php